# Google cloud deploy error - Could not retrieve the default Google Cloud Storage bucket for [project]

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Not entirely sure on the steps I need to take here. I have my rails app setup and ready to deploy on the google cloud platform the last thing to do is run `gcloud preview app deploy`

Problem is when I run it I get the errors

```
ERROR: Error Response: [403] Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not retrieve the default Google Cloud Storage bucket for [project]. Please try again or use the [bucket] argument.
root@project-small-group-1-po7p:/home/project/site/site#
```

I'm pretty sure the errors are related. From looking up the error I found enabling the google storage API can fix the issue and it created default buckets for the project. The Storage API is now enabled and I can see the buckets have been enabled but the error is still there.

Maybe I need to create some sort of permissions from the servers to the buckets but I don't know if this is the problem and if it is what steps to I need to make to setup these permissions?

What do I need to do? I have 2 instances setup and an SQL instance, with a rails app setup on them.

Comment: Where are you deploying from (i.e. your dev box, a CI system, a Google Compute Engine VM)? How did you authenticate with gcloud (`gcloud auth login` vs. a service account vs. the service account on a Compute Engine VM)?

Comment: I'm deploying from SSH on a Google Compute Engine VM. I authenticate over the in browser SSH they offer.

Comment: Is the default bucket set in ```App Engine``` -> ```settings```?

Answer (score 3):

Zachary Newman is on the right track.  Check to see if you are properly authenticated into gcloud.  I use one of two options for my projects:

```
gcloud auth login
```

OR

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON
```

I use the first for my personal testing.  I use the second on my CI service.  To create the service account JSON, from the main menu on the Google Cloud project:

- Navigate to "Permissions > Service Accounts tab".
- Click 'Create service account' button.
- Enter a useful name.
- Click on 'Furnish a new private key' checkbox
- Use the JSON key type.
- Click 'Create' button.

This is the only chance you'll get to save the JSON file so keep it safe.

Try that and see what happens.

Comment: I'm deploying from SSH on a Google Compute Engine VM. I authenticate over the in browser SSH they offer

Comment: Rob: that won't work, as your VM doesn't have the appropriate permissions for Google Cloud Storage. You can re-create a VM with the appropriate "scopes", or you can use a service account as Stanley Tso describes.